# Converting Integer to 32-bit Binary - Output is backwards

Tags: c, binary, integer, converters

I'm writing a simple program to convert an integer (between 0 and 2147483647) to 32-bit binary.

Unfortunately, the output is coming up backwards.
For example, instead of `2 = 10`, I get `2 = 01`.

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main()
{
    int finishFlag = 0; //0 = false, 1 = true

    while (finishFlag != 1)
    {
        int a[36],
            n = 0,
            i = 0, j = 0;

        printf("Enter a number between 0 and 2147483647: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        if (n > 0 && n <= 2147483647)
        {
            printf("%d expressed as a 32-bit binary number is: ", n);

            for (i = 0; i < 36; i++)
            {
                if (n == 1)
                {
                    a[i] = 1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    a[i] = n % 2;
                    n = n / 2;
                }
            }
            for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            {
                printf("%d", a[j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            finishFlag = 1;
        }
        else
            printf("\n** Not a valid input, try again ***\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, how would I display the rest of the 0's (including a space between every 8th number)? I need the output to look something like this for the integer '2'

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010
```

Comment: @immibis: I'm pretty sure Goush knows that.

Comment: @ScottHunter you'd be surprised how many people don't.

Comment: @immibis: And yet, s/he posted a question asking how to fix it.  There's a difference between knowing there is a problem and knowing *how* to fix it (or *why* your code doesn't say what you think it does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already print the digits individually; just have the `j` start at `i` and count *down* to 0.  As for printing spaces: figure out for which values of `i` you need a space, test for them, and print one only then.

Comment: Hey, thanks. It worked! Doesn't output backwards anymore. thanks so much!

Comment: get rid of the test `if (n == 1)` and loop 32 times, not 36!  Also why do you reject `0` as input?

Answer (score 1):

Well the base conversion algorithm will produce lower digits first, so you have to reverse the result to display them in usual reading order.

One way to do that:

```
void print_in_base (int value, int base)
{
    char digit[MAX_DIGITS];

    // compute digits
    int rank = 0;
    while (value != 0)
    {
        digit[rank++] = '0' + value % base;
        value /= base;
    }

    // display digits in reverse order
    while (rank--) printf ("%c", digit[rank]);
}
```

Now if you want to insert spaces every n characters, you can do something like this:

```
void print_in_base (int value, int base, int spacing)
{
    char digit[MAX_DIGITS];
    int rank = 0;
    while (value != 0)
    {
        digit[rank++] = '0' + value % base;
        value /= base;
    }
    while (rank--)
    {
        printf ("%c", digit[rank]);
        if (rank % spacing == 0 && rank != 0) printf (" ");
    } 
}
```